# Manga or manhwa about a girl who is transmigrated into a novel as the sick sister of one of the male leads and marries an assassin

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, magic, isekai

The manga or manhwa is about a girl who transmigrated into a novel as the sick sister (I think her hair is green or blue) of one of the male leads or he is a very important character in the novel... who is a duke, I think; he is a magician, the best in the kingdom.

The sister's sickness is related to her magic core, which was broken when she was young. When she is out and about in town, she passes out and the female lead, who is a saintess, tries to cure her, but I believe she fails. That female lead then becomes the brother's apprentice in magic.

The new male lead is an assassin for the villain of the novel. He is dark-skinned with white hair and red or yellow eyes. He has powers.

They meet when the male lead goes into her home to kill her brother. It was late in the night and she was on the balcony taking a breather after being transmigrated into that world. When she went to go back inside, she couldn't, because the mansion has like a spell that won't allow anyone inside when it's under attack or something like that. She told him to take her a hostage so he can run away, which he did.

The next time they meet is in town and they got married by accident because they danced; the goddess blesses who ever dances at that moment with marriage.

another detail i can add is this, this timeline where the transmigrated sister is, her future son comes back in time to warm them about some great evil, but the only one who knows of his existence on this moment in time is his uncle. it seems the great evil is the original female lead or is related to her.

the child turns himself into a lil baby bird when he is around anyone who is not the uncle.. yes the child seems to have magical powers... the last chapter i remember seeing, both the MCs where in a field of flower saying their goodbyes because she knows the original story and knows how it ends, so she wishes to be far away from him, then i think she falls asleep and he carry her, when she wakes up she kisses him a calls him darling, i think that was her future self

the style is like europeans, or historian, back in time with dukes, peasants, maids, emperors crown princes. not in ero china . idk if this helps

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: "her future son comes back in time to warm them about some great evil" - Do you recall when this scene occurs? Is it something within the first few chapters, or does it happen later in the story?

Comment: edited more info